# How to load only specific month (December) in Fullcalendar with 2 dates enables 14, 15 Dec 2012.?

Tags: date, fullcalendar

I want load only **December** month in Fullcalendar with 2 dates enables 14, 15 Dec 2012.

```
var date = new Date(2012, 11);
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth(11);
var y = date.getFullYear();
```

How it is possible? plz help me. Thanks

Comment: Dose it works: `gotoDate:  new Date(2012, 11),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer, how to render specific month on fullcalendar?

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(2012, 11));
```

This will render only **December** month on fullcalendar.